# Parse elasticsearch response in RestClient

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json, datamapper, elasticsearch, rest-client

I'm writing a Rails 3 application using Datamapper as an ORM. I'm looking at using ElasticSearch for searching but can't use the Tire gem as it seems to depend on ActiveRecord.

I'm using RestClient to submit requests to ElasticSearch but am having trouble parsing the response in ruby.

If I submit a GET request "`http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/2`", I get the following in the browser:

```
{
  "_index": "twitter",
  "_type": "tweet",
  "_id": "2",
  "_version": 3,
  "exists": true,
  "_source": {
    "user": "kimchy",
    "post_date": "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
    "message": "kimchy kimchy says"
  }
}
```

In Rails, when I type the following :

```
response = RestClient.get 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/2',{:content_type => :json, :accept => :json}
```

I get this result:

```
{
  "_index": "twitter",
  "_type": "tweet",
  "_id": "2",
  "_version": 3,
  "exists": true,
  "_source": {
    "user": "kimchy",
    "post_date": "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
    "message": "kimchy kimchy says"
  }
}
```

This looks sorta correct but I can't get data out using dot notation like I normally would with JSON.

For example, I can't write `response._type` as I get an undefined method error.

Really appreciate any help on this!

Comment: Tire does not depend on ActiveRecord, but it depends on ActiveModel. If DataMapper provides ActiveModel-compatible interface, you should be sorted.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do manual conversion, you can parse the response from json and manually convert it to an object to access fields with dot-notation.

Something like this:

```
require 'json'
require 'ostruct'

response = RestClient.get '...url...'
o = OpenStruct.new(JSON.parse(response))
```

Then you should be able to access fields with `o._type` or `o.message`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a broader answer than what you're looking for…

I use something like [this gist](https://gist.github.com/2510941) to wrap my RestClient calls to ElasticSearch. It parses JSON output, and rescues some of RestClient's exceptions to also parse and pass the server output through to the client code.

Here's the condensed version for you:

```
# url and method are provided as a param
options = { url: '...', method: '...' }

# default options
options = {
  headers: {
    accept:       :json,
    content_type: :json
  },
  open_timeout: 1,
  timeout:      1
}

begin
  request  = RestClient::Request.new(options)
  response = request.execute
  JSON.parse(response.to_str)

rescue RestClient::BadRequest => e # and others...
  # log e.message
  JSON.parse(e.response.to_str)
end
```

In the end, you get a hash parsed from ElasticSearch's JSON response.

How this all interacts with DataMapper is a bit outside my normal experience, but feel free to clarify or ask further questions in comments.